# Keep dialog form from unloading when closed

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a dialog window with a listbox containing >3000 items that takes a long time to initially load. To load this dialog, I created an instance `var dlg = new frmDlg();` and then when I need this dialog, I open it with `dlg.ShowDialog(this);` Although this reduced the number of time the listbox needs to be initialized, it still takes a long time to show the form as the dialog is unloaded from memory after the dialog closes, requiring the visual elements to be reloaded. Is there any way to keep this from happening? With a normal form, I would just hide the window instead of closing it, but this does not seem to work for dialog windows.

Comment: Intercept the FormClosing event. Set `e.Cancel = true;` and `this.Hide()`. This will hide it even if it is a dialog.

Comment: what takes too long to load - call 3000 items from DB? What you can do, load a list of your items and then pass it into a dialog form, and just set list box `datasource`

Comment: B.O.B., as I mentioned in my question, I tried hiding the window instead of closing it, but this did not work. The form still unloads when ShowDialog returns.

Comment: T.S., what takes a long time to load is the listbox itself. Once the items in the listbox are initialized, I never change them. The issue is when the dialog is closed, .NET unloads the visual portion of the listbox from memory, then reloads it into visual memory from the listbox object when ShowDialog is called again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following members to the `frmDlg`:

```
private bool keepHandle;

protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    keepHandle = e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing;
    base.OnFormClosing(e);
}

protected override void DestroyHandle()
{
    if (!keepHandle)
        base.DestroyHandle();
}
```

This should prevent the dialog's handle from being destroyed when the dialog closed by the user.

Comment: @Adam How are you populating the listbox? Could possibly be this isn't working for you because you are reloading the list each time?

Comment: Dmitry, the form's ctor is not called, but Form_Load and Form_Shown are called. This is because the form is not deleted (GC), only the Handle is destroyed.

Comment: @Dmitry My initialization logic is in the ctor.

Comment: @Dmitry I have a List<String> that is loaded ... getting Items.Count, in my test condition to make loading extremely slow, I have 44425 elements.

Comment: @Adam I've updated the answer. Please revise.

Comment: This does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 reusable = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (reusable == null) reusable = new Form2();

        reusable.ShowDialog(this);
        switch (reusable.DialogResult)
        {
            case DialogResult.OK: MessageBox.Show("Ok clicked."); break;
            case DialogResult.Cancel: MessageBox.Show("Cancel clicked."); break;
            case DialogResult.None: MessageBox.Show("Form Closed."); break;
        }
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private DialogResult dialogResult = DialogResult.None;
    public new DialogResult DialogResult
    {
        get => this.dialogResult;
        set => this.dialogResult = value;
    }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dialogResult = DialogResult.None;
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

^ Several caveats: you can no longer use the result from ShowDialog result, and you need to create your own DialogResult property, or just use a completely different / new property to represent how your dialog was hidden.

You also can't use the Button.DialogResult property anymore on any buttons, and you need to implement your own button click events to handle setting the dialog result.

This is all because of stuff that happens under the hood in the .net framework when you call ShowDialog result.

Also, Dmitry's example on using the e.CloseReason is valid too - you might want to allow closing for stuff like the application closing. That way you can also handle the FormClosed event and do any rapid cleanup you need to do before the application closes.

Comment: One other caveat on all this: You can do something similar for WPF Windows, however, you absolutely should something other than DialogResult property. This is because WPF Windows throw an exception if you try to do any of the following: 1) Try to set DialogResult on any Window that wasn't shown via ShowDialog(), 2) Try to set the DialogResult a second time.

Comment: B.O.B., I tried copying your code, but the form's Handle is still destroyed when ShowDialog returns.

Comment: @Adam I just ran a test, and the handle is indeed changing each time. It actually sounds like you might need Virtualization turned on for your listbox....

Comment: @Adam https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_ListView_VirtualMode

Comment: @Adam Basically, creating controls is a costly operation. The part that is being costly is the controls inside the listbox. Virtualization basically takes the dimensions of the parent control (listbox), and figures out the maximum number of child items it can display, maybe adds a buffer number amount, and then only every creates that many child controls. Then as the user scrolls the parent control, the child controls are just moved, and reused and their contents replaced with the active controls.

Comment: @Adam Note: that's just my high level understanding of virtualization. I could be completely wrong.

Comment: I will give that a try. Thanks